# Course page with multiple registration options

Tags: registration, page-layout, signup

I'm designing a website where people register for courses (online or physical/in-class). The difference with other websites is that every course may have multiple registration options (multiple sign-up buttons).

For example, the course "Cooking in 30 days" has three options:

- Class A - Mondays - $40
- Class B - Sundays - $40
- Class C (Online) - Fridays - $35

Currently, this is how I am doing it:

### Idea 1

[image]

- ✅ Users will Immediately see all options (no extra clicks)
- ✅ Users can compare options
- ❌ The page looks empty when only one option is available
- ❌ I can't make the signup button or card sticky (so it stays when user scrolls). The alternative I can think of is an anchor link to signup cards section like a "back to top" button.

### Idea 2

[image]

- ✅ Can make Signup card sticky
- ❌ Users can't compare options easily
- ❌ Some users (especially because we have some eldery customers) may not understand how those buttons (< and >) work

### Mobile Version of both

[image]

Which one do you think is better (and why)? Also, do you know examples of other websites doing this? I searched dribble, Google and visited some learning websites I knew like udemy, LinkedIn learning, ... but couldn't find a design for "multiple" options.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the cards sticky but you can put the price table in a block and make it sticky. [This is a Codepen example of how to do it](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/abojPjP). It even fixes the other problem, if there is only one price, the price *row* can take up the whole width of the block.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A "smaller" interface is this [example course page](https://my.adivedu.com/courses/competitive-mathematics-level-3), showing the subscription options inline, on the right side of the page.